# Excel: Find set intersections from string data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of strings made up of one or more letters, each referring to a group, like so:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | AB |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | AC |
| 5 | DX |
| 6 | FX |
| 7 | R |
| 8 | RF |
| 9 | AC |
| 10 | AB |
| 11 | CD |
| 12 | XD |

Where multi-letter strings mean that the item belongs to multiple groups, so item 1 is in `group A` only, and item 2 is in `group A` and in `group B`, and so on.

The groups themselves go from A to Z (ie there are 26 of them), and each individual item can be in no more than two groups.

I'm trying to build an Excel function that will output the size of the pairwise intersections of each of the sets A...Z, in order to calculate the overlap coefficients and other such statistics.

**EDIT** from advice in the comments:

The actual calculation is incidental - what I'm having trouble with is finding all of the set intersection sizes.

I have edited the sample data to make the output more interesting/varied. In this case, the intersections would have the following sizes:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 2 | AB | 2 |
| 3 | C | 4 |
| 4 | AC | 2 |
| 5 | DX | 2 |
| 6 | FX | 1 |
| 7 | R | 2 |
| 8 | RF | 1 |
| 9 | AC | 2 |
| 10 | AB | 2 |
| 11 | CD | 1 |
| 12 | XD | 2 |

But what I want is to output a 26x26 matrix for all of the possible pairwise intersections. This is what I'm having trouble with. Ideally, the order of the input will not matter, ie `BA` will be counted the same as `AB`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: YY is not possible so you have `26 * 25` possibilities  and `XY` is identical to `YX` so you have  325 ( `26 * 25 / 2 ` ) .  i assume right ?

Comment: Can you maybe provide the expected result for the sample data you have in your question?

Comment: is your `intersection(A,B)` some kind of calculation, or just a lookup? If lookup, then build the full table and use a lookup function for that. the rest looks trivial...

Comment: @EchoMike444 Yes it's true that the pairs are identical, but I imagined that the answer would come in the form of a matrix of which I would use only one side of the diagonal, if that makes sense? YY is possible though, as the intersection of a set with itself is just the set itself, ie YY = Y.

Comment: based on your data would need a 27x27 matrix? To cover for instance the pair (A,blank) or (blank,B). Is your "intersection" defined for those situation?

Answer (score 0):

This would maybe be easier if you separate the two values using Text to Columns with a fixed width of `1`

You can then use the following formula for the left-hand column (Column `A`, formula is in column `C` in example below):

```
 =IFERROR(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)/MIN(COUNTIF(A:B,A1),COUNTIF(A:B,B1)),"")
```

And this one for the right-hand column (Column `B`, formula is in column `D` in example below):

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)/MIN(COUNTIF(A:B,A1),COUNTIF(A:B,B1)),"")
```

To get the ratio I believe you want (if that is not what you are looking for, please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1667635/edit) to add the expected result for your mock data.

Sample results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the formula below:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=1, COUNT(SEARCH("*" & A1 & "*",$A$1:$A$12)), COUNT(SEARCH("*" & A1 & "*",$A$1:$A$12)) + COUNT(SEARCH("*" & TEXTJOIN("",1,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),,LEN(A1),-1),1)) & "*",$A$1:$A$12)))
```

Note that it works only for a maximum of 2 character combinations ie `AB` or `R` or `YZ` but not `ABC` nor `LNR`. You also need Excel 365.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very helpful! However in order to get a 26x26 matrix with all of the intersections I'm not sure how I would implement this. In the meantime I have found a pretty bulky solution, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer that, while not particularly elegant, gives my desired matrix of intersection sizes:

[Screenshot of matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK7UO.png)

The formula for the matrix is the following (Ctrl+Shift+Enter and drag):

```
=IF($C2=D$1,(SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$12,$C2,"")))),(SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$12,$C2&D$1,"")))/LEN($C2&D$1))+(SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$12,D$1&$C2,"")))/LEN(D$1&$C2)))
```

Also if anyone's interested here's the one for the unions rather than the intersections:

```
=IF($C30=D$29,(SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$12,$C30,"")))/LEN($C30)),(SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$12,$C30,"")))/LEN($C30))+(SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$12,D$29,"")))/LEN(D$29)))
```